# Array won't output data if I use a variable inside the array

Tags: php, arrays

Why does this not work?

```
    $w = '"one","two"';
    $a = array($w);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
        echo $a[$i].'<br />';
        }
```

The one above outputes: `"one","two"`

But This does?

```
    $a = array("one","two");
    for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
        echo $a[$i].'<br />';
        }
```

The one above outputs:

```
one
two
```

This has to be dynamically pulled from a database.  I'm storing the info as an array with quotes around each element.  So, when I want to pull the data I'm just going to throw a variable for that row in an array.  But, since that isn't working how do I make it work?  Thank you

Comment: could you do `$a = array(eval($w));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$w = '"one","two"';
$a = array($w);
```

Creates an array with one element `"one","two"` (check with `var_dump($a);`)

```
$a = array("one","two");
```

Creates an array with two elements `"one"` and `"two"`

If the data comes from the database as a string of comma-separated items, you could split them with `explode()`, but it is a terrible practice - you shouldn't store multiple values in a string.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are building an array with a single string `"one","two"`.

In the second example, you are building an array with two strings: `"one"` and `"two"`.

If you have a string like in example 1 that you want to turn into an array, you can use the php function `explode()`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is that the first method is outputting a string literal. Perhaps php doesn't doesn't understand how many items to put in your array...
Anyhow, you might try loading the strings "One" and "Two" into the array one at a time rather than at the point of declaration. :/